# Inconsistency in getting Keys, Values and Query for nested Rules

Tags: dataset, associations, rule, query

Querying nested `Rule` expressions of the form

```
a -> v -> b // FullForm
```

> > Rule[a,Rule[v,b]]

for `Keys`, `Values` seems inconsistent in `List` and `Association` and causes Query to fail depending on the level where these are applied:

```
data = {a -> v -> b, b -> v -> c}
```

Getting `Keys`, `Values` from `List` is consistent with the full form of each part:

```
data // Map[Keys]
```

> > {a, b}

data // Map[Values]

> > {v -> b, v -> c}

Converting to `Association` correctly gives:

```
data // Association // Map[Keys]
```

> > <|a -> v, b -> v|>

```
data // Association // Map[Values]
```

> > <|a -> b, b -> c|>

But `Query` fails in emulating `Map`

```
data // Query[All, Keys]     (*  // Normal *)
```

> > {Missing["PartInvalid", Keys], Missing["PartInvalid", Keys]}

(Similarly for `Values`).

Also fails when wrapping either the `List` or `Association` in `Dataset`

```
Dataset[Association[data]][All, Keys] // Normal
```

> > <|a -> Missing["PartInvalid", Keys],  b -> Missing["PartInvalid", Keys]|>

Tech support ticket filed. Is there a workaround?

Motivation: exploring triple-stores: data structures used in graph databases like Neo and Tiger that store relations of the form subject-verb-object, or  "alice"-> follows -> "bob".

Comment: I don't see any inconsistency with the Maps, remember Mapping over Associations only effects values

Comment: @M.R, that's right, `Map` should act on values, but in this case the values are themselves `Rules`, specifically `v->b`, `v->c`, which have valid `Keys` (`v` for both) and valid `Values` ie, (`b` and `c`)

Comment: Right, so they work as expected, Keys /@ <|a -> v -> b, b -> u -> c|> yeilds <|a -> v, 
  b -> u|> and Keys /@ {a -> v -> b, b -> u -> c} yields {a, b}. Is that not expected?

Comment: @M.R., you're right, so `Map` works but not `Query`. Will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue can be boiled down to the following inconsistency:

```
data //Query[All, Keys]
data //Query[All, g]
% /. g->Keys
```

> {Missing["PartInvalid", Keys], Missing["PartInvalid", Keys]}
>
> {g[a -> v -> b], g[b -> v -> c]}
>
> {a, b}

This suggests that you could try using the following as a workaround:

```
g[x__] := Keys[x]
data //Query[All, g]
```

> {a, b}

Comment: +1.  In version 12, the ultimate problem is in an internal function, exemplified by ``GeneralUtilities`Slice`PackagePrivate`part[a -> b, Keys]``.  The definition of that function does not allow for the fact that `Keys` (and `Values`) can operate upon expressions with the head `Rule`.

Comment: @WReach, What the hell is `Slice`? It's not in the language. Is it one of those type hacks like `Dataset` is full of? (ie C++ template looking `Vect` and `Struct`) that have nothing to do with WL expressions and pattern matching? You know there are bugs in `Dataset` that still haven't been fixed since 2014.

Comment: @alancalvitti Concidentally, in a [recent livestream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKWFw01Dve4) SW was similarly unimpressed when he saw `GeneralUtilities` appear in the `Normal` form of a `Query`.  In the discussion that followed, it was suggested that any such utility functions ought to be promoted to first-class documented functions.